# Installing Arch Linux, issue with `modprobe efivars`

Tags: linux, arch-linux, uefi, modprobe

I am trying to install Linux on my new Vaio Pro which is an adventure in and of itself. I am trying to install Arch Linux with UEFI. I am following this tutorial (though I am using newer 2013.11 Arch Linux install media).

The problem is when I try to run modprobe -r efivars or modprobe efivars it tells me:

FATAL: Module efivars not found.

I can't find a solution to this anywhere on the internet. I get no error when I run modprobe efivarfs, but then when I try to install Grub it still says: EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bit of a glitch in the tutorial for installing Archlinux on UEFI systems, but you can get past this particular hang issue like this:

You probably tried to run that modprobe command from inside the chroot of your target system. That won't get you anywhere; you need the functionality loaded in the host system's kernel. In fact my experience with the 2013.11 install media is that you don't need to load the module at all; it is already loaded. The problem is that the `sysfs` directories it uses are not accessible from inside the chroot, so that's the problem you need to fix.

1. Leave your terminal open to the chroot, but switch to a new console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)
2. Check that the `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` directory exists. If it does not, then `modprobe efivars`, but I suspect you will find it does.
3. Bind mount the directory into your choot (adjust if you are not using `/mnt`)

   ```
   mount --bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
   ```
4. Switch back to your first terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and try your next command again. Depending on where you are in the install process, your next move is probably something like this: (assumes you have the FAT32 formatted BIOS partition mounted on `/boot/efi` inside the chroot)

   ```
   grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub --recheck
   grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

If for some reason you run into problems in step #3 such as the directory you are mounting to not existing, then you haven't properly followed step #1. It is important to use the `arch-chroot` command to initialize the target system file space and only then use anther console to run the bind mount. The reason is that the `arch-chroot` script sets of several other bind mounts including ones for `/proc` and `/sys` that must be in place before you can add in the one that is missing for efi-vars. The above instructions have you opening a second console to do this specifically so you don't lose those other bind mounts while you add this one.

Comment: When running the command `modprobe efivars` from Step 2, I get the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH`. Any ideas why I would be getting this?

Comment: @Tyler that would happen if you are still in the chroot from the install procedure instead of a new root console from the archiso system as in step 1.

Comment: Regarding step 2, I am getting the same modprobe error as @TylerCrompton yet I am not in chroot. Not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: me too! (i.e.   I am not in chroot)

Comment: mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

modprobe efivarfs

modprobe efivars

Comment: I wish I had found this answer the last time I had this issue. This definitely solved my problem this time around!